# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found although network security config and certificate exist

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, retrofit, android-network-security-config

I have a server with a valid certificate and I want to communicate with it via HTTPS on android using retrofit.

I'm getting the exception when trying to use the base-url of the server with https prefix and it works just fine with http.

```
public class ModelNode {

    private final Retrofit retrofit;
    private final ModelMethodsInterface methodsInterface;
    private final Context appContext = MyApplication.getContext();
    private final String BASE_URL_EMULATOR_LOCAL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000";
    private final String BASE_URL_SERVER = "https://example.com"; //my valid url is here instead of example.com

    public ModelNode() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL_SERVER)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        methodsInterface = retrofit.create(ModelMethodsInterface.class);
    }
}
```

I do make sure I have the networkSecurityConfig attribute in my manifest

```
<application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="POLL IT"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppProject">
```

That's my network-security-config XML file and my pollitcer is a PEM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="@raw/pollitcer"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I followed https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config to establish it but still get the Exception that is mentioned in the title.

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:677)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:554)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:620)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:620)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:510)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:428)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:356)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:161)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:250)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1644)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:568)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
            ... 47 more
```

Comment: what version of Android? try an emulator with an older version to rule out the latest security tightening

Comment: Is `pollitcer` a self-signed certificate for your server, or a certificate of a custom CA? Are you sure the used certificate is correct?

Comment: it is not self signed . I got it from my university (I can see that my server certificate is valid via chrome for example).

Comment: If your server certificate is already valid then why do you add it using network security config? I would recommend to run an test on the server like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check if there are TLS and/or certificate issues.

Comment: I have same problem. My app was working fine but after 2 years I found my app could not connect to server database. I am using wcfrest services . my test of the services in browser is ok and service works fine .But in my android app I get the trust certificate error